# Не прогружается приложение

Tags: java, android

Приложение работало (и на телефоне, и на эмуляторе), но после действий с регистрацией в приложении что-то пошло не так. Само приложение устанавливается и на телефон, и на эмулятор, пытается открываться(появляется белый экран) и тут же закрывается. И ошибок никаких не выдаёт.

Comment: уже то что нужно, но лучше всего текстовую информацию прикладывать в виде текста а не картинок, это раз, два - у вас в логах есть ссылка на определенную строку в классе MainActivity (строка 44) желательно приложить ее либо фрагмент кода где она есть с указанием на эту строку :)

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка звучит так:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp
```

у вас не находит нужные ресурсы программа и как следствие происходит падение. Для решения данной проблемы вам нужно:

1. Сгенерировать `google-services.json` и положить в директорию `android/app/`. Если вы прикрутили регистрацию, значит она на базе Firebase, если она на базе этого сервиса, то там в вашей учетной записи можно сгенерировать данный файлик. Вот [ссылка_1](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592?hl=ru) и [ссылка_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367870/is-there-another-place-to-get-a-google-services-json) как это сделать.
2. Добавить `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'` в `buildscript -> dependencies` в файле `build.gradle` на уровне `root`.
3. Добавить `google()` в секцию `allprogects -> repositories` в файле `build.gradle` (упоминалось выше).
4. Добавить зависимость `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'` (версия может быть и новее) в app файла `build.gradle` и добавить a`pply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` в самый верх данного файла.
5. Сделать полный ребилд проекта с синхронизацией с файловой системой.

[Вот](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app) официальный туториал как подключать Firebase к проекту. [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52172596/9363441) откуда почерпнута информация. Если я правильно понял, то грубо говоря - вы пытаетесь использовать регистрацию в приложении, при этом не подключив правильно или вообще не подключив Firebase к проекту приложения. Просмотрите как подключать проект к данному сервису и все получится :)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но всё оказалось куда банальнее)).

Comment: рад что вы решили свою проблему :)

Answer (score 2):

Ситуация произошла из-за устаревших баз Firebase:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
```

Помогла замена баз на более новую версию:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
```